# full screen width child div with position absolute is hiding other elements

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div that's wider than its parent, and i found many solutions.
Almost all of them say something that looks like this:

```
position:absolute; 
left:0; 
right:0;
```

(for example: [How to expand child <div> with 100% of body width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472110/how-to-expand-child-div-with-100-of-body-width))

This is indeed a solution, but there is only one little problem.

situation:
([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gx4p2red/2/))

```
<style>
.parent
{
    width:70%; 
    padding: 1%;
}
.fullwidth
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
</style>  
<div class="parent">

    <div>
        <h1>
            This is a normal div. 
            This text is visible
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="fullwidth">
        <h1>
            This is a full width div.
        </h1>
    </div>

    <div class="normal-div">
        <h1>
            This is a normal div
            This text is hiding behind fullwidth div
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this example, the second normal div is hiding behind the fullwidth div, because the fullwidth is absolute positioned.

So, how can you do this without having the divs hide behind the fullwidth div?

Comment: Yes, close the parent div and open it again after the full width div - http://jsfiddle.net/gx4p2red/5/

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, but in some cases, you can't do that. Imagine that you are doing this in a grid system with nested rows. then you will have to close multiple rows and it won't look the same...

Comment: So? Either you want a full width div or you don't...a full width div wouldn't be part of a grid system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes to the "normal div":

1. Position relative (the default is static)
2. Set z-index below that of the absolute positioned div

And one change to the absolute div (set its z-index below the "normal" div).

http://jsfiddle.net/gx4p2red/3/

```
.fullwidth
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;

    /*Testing only*/
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 0;
}

/*Testing only*/
.normal-div
{
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work... I'm rigt now viewing it on ipad